# Screen sharing and tem viewer in android to android

Tags: android, screensharing

I want to implement screen sharing functionality in my app like we use team viewer.

I search a lot for third party tool.

One tool i have worked is opentok(Tolkblox). But it want give exact facility like Team viewer and its sample example is also not work like a screen shring should be.

I don't find any third party tool for this requirement.

If anyone any idea regarding this then please reply for the same.

Answer (score 2):

**Screen capturing and sharing in Android 5.0**

You have the possibility with Android 5.0 to use the [android.media.projection](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/projection/package-summary.html) for screen sharing. But I don't know if this fits your needs.

> Android 5.0 lets you add screen capturing and screen sharing capabilities to your app with the new android.media.projection APIs. This functionality is useful, for example, if you want to enable screen sharing in a video conferencing app. For more see [this](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-5.0.html).

**Team Viewer SDK**

You can also use the [SDK from TeamViewer](https://integrate.teamviewer.com/de/develop/). As far as I know, with this you can also remotely control the other device.

I hope I did understand your question right and this helps you a bit.

Comment: Thanks for the  answer  but  i don't want to record the mobile screen , create video ,I want exact feature like screen sharing example like sky pe